# ¿Cómo llamar función al crear instancia de modelo?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

Perdon por la consulta, sigo aprendiendo cada vez mas de Django esta vez tengo un problema con respecto a una función que necesito que se ejecute luego de crear una instancia de un modelo, en palabras rápidas el asunto es de la siguiente manera, tengo un modelo de `Pedido`, en el una función que toma el total, y la función que me interesa que modificara otro modelo `Cuenta` a partir de los datos de `Pedido` ya modifique el método `save()` de la siguiente manera:

```
# Modificacion del Metodo Save
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
# Funcion que necesito que ralice el cambio en el modelo Cuenta
self.suma_saldos()
```

El llamado funciona bien pero no me retorna los valores necesarios para la función `suma_saldos()` enviándome valores en 0, no se si tendría que usar otro método o otra manera de realizar esta función, cabe resaltar que todo esto lo estoy realizando en el `models.py` se que mi función  `suma_saldos()` funciona bien porque la llame en otro metodo que me muestra unos datos en el `admin.py`, pero esta se llamaba cada vez que refrescaba la pagina, y me estaba sumando valores erróneos, por favor ayúdenme a resolver el problema estoy trabajando con Django 2.1.7 y python 3.7.3 Gracias.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo de una manera mejor, y seria con `signals` o señales, es una buena opción a emplear. Si no estas informado de como funcionan, investiga sobre el tema, es bastante simple.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes especificar que valores de tu modelo `Pedido` envias a la función `suma_saldos()` de la siguiente manera:

```
self.suma_saldos(self.id, self.fecha_creacion)
```

cabe aclarar que tendrías que modificar tu función `suma_saldos()` para que reciba los parámetros que necesitas.